# Images dynamically in the datalist didnot appear on the server

Tags: asp.net, image, publish, datalist, remote-server

In my web application I have a datalist. I need to insert some images after every 3 items. The code is as given:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dlHomeContent.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && i % 3 == 0)
            {
                imgPath = "~/Advertisement/homeadvt" + adCnt + ".jpg";
                if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/Advertisement/homeadvt" + adCnt + ".jpg")))
                {
                    HtmlGenericControl divAdv = new HtmlGenericControl();
                    divAdv = (HtmlGenericControl)dlHomeContent.Items[i - 1].FindControl("divAdv");
                    divAdv.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    divAdv.Attributes.Add("class", "show-control");
                    Image imgAdvt = new Image();
                    imgAdvt = (Image)dlHomeContent.Items[i - 1].FindControl("imgAdvt");
                    imgAdvt.ImageUrl = imgPath;
                }                    
                adCnt++;
            }
        }
```

The images are placed inside Advertisement folder which is under the root project. This is working perfect in my local machine. But when i published this to a remote server(set on amazon), the images did not show up. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dlHomeContent.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && i % 3 == 0)
            {
                imgPath = "~/Advertisement/homeadvt" + adCnt + ".jpg";
                if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/Advertisement/homeadvt" + adCnt + ".jpg")))
                {
                    HtmlGenericControl divAdv = new HtmlGenericControl();
                    divAdv = (HtmlGenericControl)dlHomeContent.Items[i - 1].FindControl("divAdv");
                    divAdv.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    divAdv.Attributes.Add("class", "show-control");
                    Image imgAdvt = new Image();
                    imgAdvt = (Image)dlHomeContent.Items[i - 1].FindControl("imgAdvt");
                    imgAdvt.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("/Advertisement/homeadvt" + adCnt + ".jpg");
                }                    
                adCnt++;
            }
        }
```

You should save the image location after mapped with your project folder.

Comment: imgAdvt.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("/Advertisement/homeadvt" + adCnt + ".jpg"); this is the point suj..